# Sign in as different user in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, user-accounts

I use *SharePoint 2013* and I need to change my current user in my SharePoint site.

How can I change my current user?

How can I add sub menu (sign in as different user) to my menu ?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is Microsoft solution: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752600

Basically, start the browser as a different user.

Another solution (but dirty) is to edit the Welcome.aspx file and add a control:

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="ID_LoginAsDifferentUser" Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuser%>" Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuserdescription%>" MenuGroupId="100" Sequence="100" UseShortId="true" />
```

more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint__cloud/archive/2012/12/20/where-is-quot-sign-in-as-different-user-quot-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Comment: Hi Robert, 1 way is to modify the CONTROLTEMPLATES\welcome file. What is on your view of doing this via master page?

Comment: Hi! Are we talking about building our own control, add the missing control outside of the menu, or something else? I do not really follow (since welcome is already used in master page to render the menu etc)

Comment: If you modify welcome page then it would apply to entire SharePoint2013 server. However, if one wishes to use the 'sign in as diff user' link on say only one webapplication then, wont it be better option to add it in master page right above the existing signout? And I beleive it is not good practice to touch hive files.. So isnt master page edit a better solution? No one has provided this as an solution.

Comment: You can provide anything you like as solution :) your approach do require creating at least a copy of the existing masterpage, and edit that one (to make sure nothing gets changed by future updates) though :) my response is focusing on Microsofts approach (run the actual browser as another user), I consider the welcome-modification to be a hack :)

Comment: OK, I have posted another answer to this question, hope it will help the OP and users...

Answer (score 11):

There is a free tool from Pointbird that will give you this functionality, or you could just add a custom action that adds a link to `"/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true"`

http://pointbird.com/products/pointbird-sign-in-as-different-user/

http://www.cwheeler76.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=2

Answer (score 5):

Create a bookmarklet that points to :

```
URL=javascript:window.location = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl.replace(/\/$/, "") + "/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true"
```

As something you deploy to your browser, rather than your site, it approaches the problem from the other direction.  But honestly, most of your users won't need this functionality - developers will.

Another advantage of this approach is the same bookmarklet will work in *any* SharePoint environment, including Office 365.

Comment: This will apply to only one user. How can we enable this to all users??

Comment: @Yayati you'll need to use a different approach if you want it for all users. Personally I'd use Anders Rasks's suggestion of a custom action for that.

Answer (score 3):

Edit `Welcome.aspx` file in this address :

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\
15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES
```

And then after tag with Id `ID_RequestAccess` most add this Tag :

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="ID_LoginAsDifferentUser"   
         Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuser%>"     
         Description=" <%$Resources:wss,
                                 personalactions_loginasdifferentuserdescription%>"     
         MenuGroupId="100"   Sequence="100"   UseShortId="true"   />
```

This is my source link. [Sign in as different user in SharePoint 2013](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/Sign-in-as-a-Different-User-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your question is about multiple requirements:-

> I need to change my current user in my SharePoint site.
>
> How can I change my current user?
>
> How can I add sub menu (sign in as different user) to my menu ?

So, here there are 3 solutions:-

**1.  Launch your web browser as another user**

For IE --> Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer and drag iexplore.exe to the desktop (creates a shortcut) --> Right click your new shortcut and select “Properties” --> Modify the shortcut target by adding runas and the desired user account to the beginning of the path. Change the target to (replace user@domain with your test acct):

> ```
> %systemroot%\System32\runas.exe /user:user@domain "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
> ```

Click OK to save changes.

[Reference](http://www.little.org/blog/2012/07/17/launch-your-web-browser-as-another-user/)

**2.  Modify the welcome.aspx page in control templates (HIVE)**

Locate the file \15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\Welcome.ascx and open in a text editor --> Add the following element before the existing element with the id of “ID_RequestAccess”:

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="ID_LoginAsDifferentUser"  
Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuser%>"  
Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuserdescription%>" 
MenuGroupId="100"  
Sequence="100"  
UseShortId="true"  />
```

Save the file --> Now, the menu item shall be displayed.

[Reference](http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/sign-in-as-different-user-and-sharepoint-2013/)

**3. Modify the SharePoint MasterPage via Designer or VS module**

Open the master page --> Search for `<div id="suiteBarButtons">` --> Scroll and paste the below code between the `<SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate ....>` and `</SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate>` tag --> Add the foll. code:

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_SignInAsDifferentUser"
         Text="SignIn As Different User"
         Description="To log in as a different user"
         MenuGroupId="200"
         Sequence="250"
         UseShortId="true"
         ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true"
         PermissionMode="All" />
```

This will add the 'sign is as another user' into the site actions dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

Much like Derek Gusoff, I use a bookmarklet. Thought I would post it in the interest of added options.

```
javascript:(function(){ var curloc = document.location.href.split('_');var urlEnding= '_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true';curloc = curloc.splice(0,curloc.length-1).join('_')+urlEnding;document.location.href = curloc;})();
```